# ImageMagick. Putting Redaction on a document without changing quality and size of document

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, imagemagick-identify

I am new to ImageMagick.I need to create redaction over a document(.doc ) and image formats in order to cover some texts with help of ImageMagick . Then, I have to convert it to .tif format.I don't want to change size of document as I want to perform with default size.What should be command for that?

Answer (score 2):

I finally got the answer for image it's:
convert image.png -draw "fill black rectangle x1,y1,x2,y2" output.tif

where x1,x2,y1,y2 are the co-ordinates from left hand top corner of the image.

Comment: Your question was about redacting a MS-Word document, not a PNG image. Be VERY WARY of what you are doing... http://hackaday.com/2008/08/01/exposing-poorly-redacted-pdfs/